# Induced electricity on earthed conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

The suggested answer is (C).  However, I think that upon earthing, both X and Y should become negatively charged, due to the induction from Z.  What does the community think?

PS: note that the Z is not earthed, although the picture might be a bit misleading!

Comment: Probably when this problem was copied from somewhere else they forgot to include the step 'then X und Y are separated' before grounding Y (how else can you just ground Y). Then C is also not correct....